# ExtJS 5.1 won´t send a nested JSON object to my server

Tags: json, post, extjs

I am trying to send a nested JSON object to my server through my store´s proxy. I am using ExtJS 5.1 and in the code below I have used the `hasMany` attribute to specify the nested JSON model.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.PersonStore',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
     storeId: 'PersonStore',
     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'http://localhost:80/index.php?person=create', 
        reader: {
           type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
           type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     idProperty: 'id',
     fields: [
         {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
     ],
     hasMany: {
         model: 'MyApp.model.Item',
         name: 'items',
         associationKey: 'items'    
     } 
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Item',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model', 
     fields: [
         {
             name: 'id', 
             type: 'int'
         },
         {
             name: 'itemType', 
             type: 'string'
         }
     ],
     belongsTo: 'MyApp.model.Person'     
});
```

Then in my controller when creating a new Person, i do this:

```
var store = grid.getStore();
store.add({name: 'Steve', age: '50'});
var lastInsertedPerson = store.last();
var items = lastInsertedPerson.items();
items.add({itemType: 'item1'}); 
items.add({itemType: 'item2'}); 

store.sync();
```

Then the POST request is sent in this format:

```
{"id":"MyApp.model.Person-1", "name":"Steve", "age":"50"}
```

but I expect it to be:

```
{"id":"MyApp.model.Person-1", "name":"Steve", "age":"50", "items":[{"itemType":"item1"}, {"itemType":"item2"}]}
```

So why does not the json object in the POST request contain the nested `Item` object?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the nested data to be present in the post object you have to set a config in the parent model's proxy's writer object.  So if you change your `Person` model to look something like the code below the nested objects should come through:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
    ],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Item',
        name: 'items',
        associationKey: 'items'
    },
    proxy: {
        url: '/url/to/your/backend/service',
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            allDataOptions: {
                associated: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the writer has a `partialDataOptions` config as well, so if you want the nested data to come through in a PUT the `associated` config will have to be set there as well.  See the [Ext Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.data.writer.Writer.html) for more details on the writer configuration options.